# How would you model Rust procedural macros?

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus, higher-order-logic

In Rust programming language one can write a compiler extension function that works on abstract syntax tree, effectively modifying source code before it gets converted into machine instructions.
In other words, macro function has signature

```
 Abstract Syntax Tree -> Abstract Syntax Tree
```

Can these be thought of as higher order functions? Usually higher order functions use function composition to produce their output, not source code manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't consider it a higher-order function.  A [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) takes a function as input, or yields a function as its output.  In contrast, it sounds to me like your compiler extension is accepting data as input (the abstract syntax tree) and producing data on its output.

I suppose you could consider the AST a specification of a function, but that seems like a stretch to me.

I'm not sure that what name you attach to it matters much, from a computer science perspective.  A rose by any other name, and all that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see how operations on AST are merely data manipulation. I was looking for formalism capable of capturing the fact that the result of AST manipulation is executable code. A function.

Fn->AST-><Modify AST>->AST->Fn

which simplifies to Fn->Fn

Comment: @AndrewButenko, you can call it a higher-order function if you want, as long as it doesn't cause confusion.